# How to override a base class's default options in a derived class

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else; I've seen several questions with similar titles but I can't seem to determine how the answers would apply to my case.

What I would like to do is define a base class, which sets some default option, for instance, landscape orientation. Then, I would like to define a derived class which loads the base class, but changes that default back to portrait orientation. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. In the MWE below, when I load `base-class`, the default is landscape orientation as desired. When I load `base-class` with the `letterpaper` option, the orientation changes to portrait, as expected. However, when I load `derived-class`, the orientation remains landscape rather than `letterpaper`. How can I do this? There are additional differences between the classes (though much in common) that make me want to not just load `base-class` with the `letterpaper` option. (And of course, I could manually specify the `letterpaper` option when loading `derived-class`, but I'd like to just set the default if possible in order to avoid that.) My guess is that the issue is because when `derived-class` loads `base-class`, `base-class` will execute the `landscape` option and override the `letterpaper` option. But I'm not sure how to fix that.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{base-class.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} \ProvidesClass{base-class}

    \DeclareOption{landscape}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

    \ExecuteOptions{landscape}

    \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
    \ProcessOptions\relax

    \LoadClass{article}
    
    % Insert much additional material here
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{derived-class.cls}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} \ProvidesClass{derived-class}

    \DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{base-class}}

    \ExecuteOptions{letterpaper}

    \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{base-class}}
    \ProcessOptions\relax

    \LoadClass{base-class}
    
    % Additional style differences
\end{filecontents}

%\documentclass{base-class} % Landscape
%\documentclass[letterpaper]{base-class} % Portrait
\documentclass{derived-class} % Landscape (portrait desired)
%\documentclass[letterpaper]{derived-class} % Portrait

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: apart from the actual coding question, your desired behaviour seems unconventional and unlike the behaviour in the standard classes. I would expect letterpaper/a4paper options to be completely independent of landscape/portrait options. Why would you expect `[landscape,letterpaper]` to be portrait orientation? One pair of options says which way round the paper is positioned, and the other says the paper size?

Comment: Huh, for some reason I have been mistaken about this for a while. At some point I set up a (different) class that defaults to landscape orientation, but also wanted to be able to use it in portrait in some cases. Setting the portrait option didn't properly override the default landscape option, but setting letterpaper did, which got it into my head that that was the way to do it. Good to know that things aren't quite as weird as I thought!